# Angular Formly - Focus on the first editable element

Tags: angular, focus, angular-formly

In our project, we used **Angular Formly** to generate complex forms (with complex grouping). I checked the component documentation, but I couldn't find any sample or solution for finding the first editable component (like a `textbox`) and set the focus on it when the form or component is loaded.

Comment: You can just pass `focus: true` to your `FormlyFieldConfig` of your first element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to check a "group of any" It's util use a directive. A Directive with a selector of formControl and formControlName like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[formControl], [formControlName]'
})
export class InputDirective {

  constructor(private controlDir: NgControl,private el:ElementRef) { }

}
```

Give access to all the "inputs" control by a FormControlName or a FormControl

In our form, we can get all of them using viewChildren

```
@ViewChildren(InputDirective) inputs:QueryList<InputDirective>
```

And in ngAfterViewInit we can make some like

```
ngAfterViewInit()
{
   const input=this.inputs?this.inputs.find(x=>x.controlDir.enabled):null
   if (input)
       input.el.nativeElement.focus()
}
```